# Apply to target server failed for Job

Tags: sql-server

SQL JOB Scheduler - Its working perfectly. but instead of "." if I am giving my computer IP its giving me exception

> Apply to target server failed for Job.

I need to create job in remote server. How can I do that. If I am giving that server IP its not able Create Job by Connect and Display already exist Job

```
JobAgent.CreateSqlJob(sqljobCredentials, SqlJobThings.SqlJobSteps, SqlJobThings.SqlJobAlerts,
                SqlJobThings.SqlJobSchedule);
```

Comment: Try with port number `<<IP Address>>,<<port number>>`.  Something like `192.168.1.101,1433`

Comment: I tried This also Getting Same Error : Apply to target server failed for Job 'job12_DPL'.

exception.InnerException.Message :  An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.

Comment: But Connectivity Happen Working Fine Like your solution. But , Not able to create SQL Server Jobs "Error : Apply to target server failed for Job 'job12_DPL'. exception.InnerException.Message : An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch."

Comment: Are you trying from Job Scheduler or C# Code?

Comment: C# Code - Server Name we tried

Comment: Can you please post your code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233664/discussion-between-naveen-s-and-akshay-gaonkar).